# Nutch Raw Html Saving

Tags: nutch

I'm trying to get raw html of crawled pages in different files, named as url of the page. Is it possible with **Nutch** to save the raw html pages in different files by ruling out the indexing part?

Comment: You can look at this post
[How do I save the origin html file with Apache Nutch][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007178/how-do-i-save-the-origin-html-file-with-apache-nutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no direct way to do that. You will have to do few code modifications.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007178/how-do-i-save-the-origin-html-file-with-apache-nutch/10060160#10060160) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123757/how-to-get-the-html-content-from-nutch).

Comment: Thanks, for the ones looking for the answer, the answer in the first link is useful.